# How to remove white space between images on wordpress mobile version?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I have been searching for a while trying different methods to try and remove white space between my images on the home screen on my mobile version. It only occurs on my mobile version. My url for the site is below:

https://athleteperks.co.uk

I also have a thin small white gap between two images on my home screen which wold also be great to remove. It would be great if someone could help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the bottom 5 images before the footer there is padding that needs to be removed on mobile state 767 like so:

```
.fw-row .blog-grid-items {
   padding:0;
}
.blog-grid-items .blog-item.col-sm-sf-5 {
   padding:0;
}
```

Adding the above CSS makes the last 5 images full width on mobile and eliminates white space.

Also removing the below CSS eliminates the small 1px gap between the two images on your home screen:

```
.row:not(.fw-row) .spb_swift-slider .swift-slider {
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

**Edited Answer**
The below CSS needs to be added to your stylesheet in order to remove the white space from the images on mobile:

```
.spb_text_column, .spb_content_element {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Mobile media query */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .swift-slider-outer {
        height: auto !important;
    }
}
```

**In order for the above media query to work you must have in your head file the following:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm referring to the "view perks" and "view flash perks" "our partners" and the "try our free version" images which have gaps all between them. thanks

Comment: No problem @max and If my solution worked can you please accept my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm referring to the "view perks" and "view flash perks" "our partners" and the "try our free version" images which have gaps all between them. thanks

Comment: Ok @max I have edited my answer please refer to it again.

Comment: Thank you so much! that has worked! I cant seem to find the ".row:not(.fw-row) .spb_swift-slider .swift-slider {
   margin-left: 0;
}" in my style sheet though. thanks

Comment: `.row:not(.fw-row) .spb_swift-slider .swift-slider {
   margin-left: 0;
}` is what you need to add to your stylesheet, it is currently set to `.row:not(.fw-row) .spb_swift-slider .swift-slider {
   margin-left: -1px;
}` which is causing the 1px gap and you need to add the code to remove it to your stylesheet. And if you can accept my answer that would be great!

Comment: Just found out that the code ".swift-slider-outer {
    height: auto !important; " removes my slider at the top my homepage.

Comment: You should probably make sure in that case that you are only using that code within a mobile media query, which will make sure that it only triggers height auto on mobile at 767 and below.

Comment: Please could you tell me how that is formatted? thanks

Comment: @max I have edited my answer to so you can see the media query for mobile and I am pasting it here for you too, if you add this to your stylesheet it will only target mobile screens and on desktop your slider will be fine: `@media (max-width: 767px) {
        .swift-slider-outer {
            height: auto !important;
        }
    }` However in order for the above CSS to work, you must have in your head file the following: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

here is the code if you want to rid out the space in between the 5 images in the same row:

```
.col-sm-sf-5 {
   width: 25%;
   padding: 0px;
float: left;
}

.row:not(.fw-row) .spb_swift-slider .swift-slider {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.row {
   margin-left: -15px;
   margin-right: -15px;
}
.blog-grid-items .blog-item {
   margin: 0 0 0px;
   height: 330px;
   padding-top: 0;
}
```

If you want to modify the design only for a mobile version, with resolution 1024 px, add this code and put inside this code your new classes above.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
   .classname {
       /* other styles here */
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm referring to the "view perks" and "view flash perks" "our partners" and the "try our free version" images which have gaps all between them. I used the following code ".swift-slider-outer {
    height: auto !important;" however this made my slider on my home screen disappear. Is there any way to have it only for mobile and for it not remove my home slider? thanks